# How to choose a relevant threshold for HWE

Tags: hypothesis-testing, biostatistics, bioinformatics, false-discovery-rate

I'm a beginner in biostatistics and GWAS study.

For a quality control (pre-imputation), I need to perform a chi-square test on each SNP (there are 700 000 of them) to test the deviation for Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium. Once I got my list of p-values, I need to choose a relevant threshold. My idea is to plot a histogram of $-\log(p)$ and choose the threshold so that I can still have the majority of my data. On my histogram, it seems that a threshold of $10^{-6}$ is fine.

However my approach seems too naive since I did not use the False Discovery Rate and the correction of Benjamini-Hochberg. What should I do ? Should I compute the q-values and then proceed as previously ? (Plot the histogram of $-\log(q)$ and choose the threshold for q-values on it ?)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You normally use the FDR procedure to control for false discoveries (Type I error, incorrectly rejecting null hypothesis). For example, in testing gene expression, you want to control for genes that don't show difference in expression but by chance have < 0.05 because of the number of test conducted.

The issue you have is the opposite. The chi-square tells you how much the distribution of the genotypes deviate from Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium (if I get my undergraduate genetics correct). The null hypothesis is the SNPs obey HWE and those that have a low p-value (you reject), are those that you don't trust and what to discard.

Hence, FDR doesn't apply here. You want to control for false negatives (type II error) You can take a cutoff and retain SNPs that are > a p-value threshold.

Comment: Is it not important in that case to also control Type I error ? If we reject a marker that was in HWE, we loose a relevant SNP for the rest of the study.

Comment: have you tried doing it? my point is.. everything comes at a cost, you apply an fdr, you gain more snps that have a low p-value, but you also include some that truly fail HWE

Comment: I suggest you run some simulations with true and false positives to understand my point..

Comment: Yes, but also: in this case (SNPchip QC) the test isn't really about whether the alleles are in HWE in the population, it's more about failure of genotyping or failure of the calling algorithm for a SNP, which tends to cause absolutely *massive* apparent failures of HWE.  When I did this, we picked a threshold and looked at raw probe intensity data for a few SNPs near the threshold to  make sure 'bad' SNPs aren't being missed.